# It is possible to create trigger invoked on EVERY send email message?

Tags: apex, trigger, email, connected-apps

i want to make a thing witch one will be working with **every** sent email from my org. It is possible to write a trigger to do that?
The only possibility that comes to my mind is create a factory to send emails. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, it's not very clear what it is that you're asking. To me, it feels like you're asking about two separate things (a trigger for `emailmessage`, and a utility class for sending emails). I think it'd help to take a step back and describe your overall goal. What is it that you're trying to achieve with emails? Generally speaking, the more details you can give us, the better. You can [edit] your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. Let me know if it helps:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2009/10/one-of-the-things-about-working-for-a-company-that-innovates-at-such-an-incredible-pace-is-that-you-are-constantly-tasked-wit.html

Comment: Yes this is it. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: While it's useful to have a link, please remember that links can be invalidated over time. We recommend including the essential information in the answer itself. Please read [answer] for more information on what we expect in a good answer.